# trac wiki: how do I display the current date

Tags: wiki, trac

I want to create a fully printable document in the trac wiki markup.
For this I need the current date as text on the page.

suggestions?

regards
Ronny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [trac macro](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiMacros) in python.

an example that does format timestamps is available 
in the [trac sources](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-0.11/sample-plugins/Timestamp.py)